# Conflicting definitions of Bulk-to-Boundary propagators in AdS

Tags: greens-functions, ads-cft, propagator

This problem has to do with bulk reconstruction in AdS/CFT. It is given that the bulk-to-boundary propagator can be obtained from the bulk-to-bulk propagator by the following relation (c.f. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-fall-2008/lecture-notes/ in lecture number 16)

$K(z,x;z^{'},x^{'}) \equiv \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}} \vec{n}. \partial G$

where $K$ is the bulk to boundary propagator, $G$ is the bulk to bulk propagartor (i.e the Green's function satisfying the following relation $(\Box - m^{2})G = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\delta^{d+1}(x - x^{'})$ and $\gamma$ is the boundary metric (in AdS, given in Poincare coordinates).

Now, in the following paper in Appendix A, Equation number (69) has the following definition for the same (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0606141)

$\Phi(x^{'}) = \int d\tau d\Omega \frac{R^{D-2}}{\cos^{D-2}(\rho)}(\phi\partial_{\rho}G - G\partial_{\rho}\phi)|_{\rho \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}$

which then defines $K$ via the definition

$\Phi(x^{'}) = \int d\tau d\Omega K(x|x^{'})\Phi_{0}(x^{'})$

where $\Phi_{0}$ is the boundary value of the field $\Phi$, which satisfies the equation $(\Box - m^{2})\Phi = 0$ everywhere, and $G$ is again the Green's function.

Therefore, we have two definitions of the bulk-to-boundary propagator, via the Green's function (One given in the MIT OCW lectures and the other in that hep-th arXiv paper). Clearly both must be the same. **My problem is to derive one from the other.** Or, at the very least, to find some logical relation between the two,

The first definition is in Poincare coordinates, where the AdS metric is as follows

$ds^{2} =\frac{dz^{2} + dx^{2}}{z^{2}}$

with $x \equiv (t,x_{i})$

And the second definition is in the Global coordinates, and so the metric there is

$ds^{2} = \frac{R^{2}}{\cos^{2}(\rho)}(-d\tau^{2} + d\rho^{2} + \sin^{2}(\rho)d\Omega^{2}_{d-1})$

Both results are in $d+1$ dimensional space-time. For ease of computation, $d$ is taken to be odd. Also, I've been told that part of the hint lies in the usage of Green's Second Identity. Couldn't do much with it myself.

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27072/2451